# Hide export symbols without using a DEF file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dllexport

I would like to hide exported symbols from a DLL for obfuscation purposes.

That is pretty neatly doable when using a module definition file (`.def`) looking something like this;

```
EXPORTS  
??0Foo@QAE@XZ   @1   NONAME
??1Foo@QAE@XZ   @2   NONAME
?Bar@Foo@UAEHXZ @3   NONAME
```

Trouble is, such solution is highly inflexible and demands manual work. As you can see within my example, I am exporting C++ symbols, hence they are heavily decorated by my compiler.

So my current workflow looks like this;

I have to first create a version of my DLL that exports all symbols in the standard way using `__declspec(dllexport)`, then I need to extract all exported symbol names using `dumpbin` or alike. After that is done, I need to copy&paste the symbols into my module definition file and add that `NONAME` directive. Then I have to make sure that my original sources do not use that `__declspec(dllexport)` anymore. Once all of that is done, I need to activate that .def file within the project settings and then I can finally build the export symbol free version of that DLL. Plenty of work for that rather simple task, I guess.

Before covering all of this using a bunch of scripts and stuff, I thought that **maybe, just maybe there is a solution that is much simpler**?

Please note that I am using VisualStudio (2012) and hence that nifty GCC `pragma hidden` wont do, as far as I know.

Comment: I would have thought there was a way to do it with a `__declspec` as well, but alas, the documentation for exporting by ordinal exclusively is [unfortunately pretty clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7tsx612(v=vs.110).aspx) : "..you must use a .def file instead of __declspec(dllexport)." Kinda blows. I guess MS just didn't think it important enough to expose as  another one of their extensions.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for your ressurance. So I will go ahead and build a bunch of scripts to do that job. Hey, finally a task that I could cover using my upcoming Python wizardry :D.